# FullCalendar agendaWeek view rendering issue on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

New to FullCalendar and I am using the agendaWeek view and it is embedded inside a tab which is an inhouse built tabs control and not jquery ui tabs.  The issue is on load events are not being displayed and the calendar also is not rendered properly ie the display times on the leftmost column do not align correctly.  As soon as I click on the calendar the events will display and the time column will be aligned.  And when i debug it is due to this line in my code on the select event:
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);

I have read countless threads about how we need to add this: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); on the show event of the tab and I have tried to do so but no luck.  The initial load always do not show the events and have styling issues.  When I debug in the console the line of code is being executed but nothing happens.  If i move this code to another page without the tabs it works perfectly fine.  I also noticed sometimes it will render correctly when I inspect an element in developer console.

Anyone has similar issue?  Appreciate any thought.

[Image of calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liTRr.png)

Code that activates tab:

```
showActiveTab: function () {
    var _this = this;

    switch (this.activeTab) {
        case "customerTab":
            CustomerTab.focus();
            break;
        case "OrderTab":
            OrderTab.focus();
            break;
        case "CalendarTab":
            CalendarTab.focus();
            break;
    }

    _this.activeTab.scrollTop(0).show();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }, 1000);             
},
```

Comment: Can you put your code in your question so we can see what might be the problem.

Comment: Hi Rob, added some code segment, thank you!

Comment: any solution foe this?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, did you come to any sort of resolution?